# Is there any way to mirror an object using SKAction in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an object (SKNode) that contains two other objects (SKSpriteNode).

What is the right way to mirror combined objects?

What I have:

[image: image I want to mirror]

What I want:

[image: image I want to have]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SKAction* action = [SKAction scaleBy:-1.0 duration:10.0];

[node runAction:action];
```

Pretty much the same as LearnCocos2D but I know you asked for an SKAction.

Answer (score 2):

Flipping is the same as inversing scale:

```
theNode.xScale = -1.0;
theNode.yScale = -1.0;
```

Apply it to the parent node and it should flip the child nodes around the center of their parent node.